# SubSonic 3.0.0.3 | SimpleRepository | saving byte[] to varbinary

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I have a Model, with a property of type `byte[]`, with corresponding field equivalent on SQL Server of type `varbinary(128)`.

Saving went well. but the problem is my password field is always NULL.

```
guser.Password = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sample");
repo.Add(guser);
```

Is this a bug or a user error?

Comment: I just convert VarBinary to NVvarChar, for now that i am not receiving any answer as of the moment.

Comment: I also need to add a byte[] field and I have also discovered that Subsonic does not create the new field in the database during Migration.